# return html data from Ajax call cause JQTouch app to freeze

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I'm using in jQTouch the function to return successfully html data from PHP code.
The data is displayed below the calling form and then the app freeze.

```
$('#ajax_post').submit(function(event,info){
     var text = $("input[type=text]", this);
            text.blur();
    var results = $('#results');
    $.post('processgia.php',$("#ajax_post").serialize(), function(data) { 
results.html(data);});
```

I'm using the html form in to making the Ajax call.

```
<form id="ajax_post" class="form current" method="POST" action="processgia.php">
<ul class="rounded">
<li>
    <input type="text" name="anumber" value="" placeholder="Report Number:"/></li>
</ul>
<ul class="rounded">
<li> <input type="text" name="weight" value="" placeholder="Weight:" >
<a style="top:12px; right:20px;color:rgba(0,0,0,.1)" href="#" class="submitwButton">Search</a> </li> </ul></form> <div id="results"></div>
```

What is wrong in the code that cause the app to freeze after displaying the html data correctly?
how can I redirect the same data to another page?

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? Is the app you mention here is mobile browser?